# SImple quiestion about page navigation and back button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to learn the way how I can navigate between pages in win phone 8.1.

I have seen that when I want to go to a new page, I have to use this code:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

But my doubt is what happens when I do it. I mean that I just use as parameter the type of the page that I want to go, so this create a new page? and when I click the back button, the page is dispose, deleted from memory? If the actual page is deleted when I click the back button, it would possible to avoid this behavior and keep alive to return to the same page to preserve the state and the data that could have the controls like textboxes?

Thanks.

Comment: refer this link http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/05/23/windows-phone-8-1-frame-page-navigationhelper-suspensionmanager.aspx